# Unable to place a headless LWC on Case page

Tags: lightning-web-components, case, page-layout, quickaction, headless-lwc

I created a headless LWC for a Record Action according to the documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232

I'm trying to use the Summer 21 feature which enables using an LWC directly as an action as opposed to wrapping it with an Aura component.

I placed it in my page layout in the lightning & mobile actions layout, but it doesn't show.

Metadata XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>Action</actionType>
            <objects>
                <object>Case</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I've tried it with and without the RecordPage target.

This has worked for us with a custom object, but not on Case.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - no it doesn't, because I'm trying to use this without wrapping in Aura components as has been enabled in Summer 21

Comment: you might want to look again and read past the fact that it's an aura wrapper as it's related to actions behaving differently on Cases. For example, do you have feed tracking enabled on Cases? If "yes", have you tried dragging the "Chatter" component onto your lightning page to confirm the QA displays there? You can refer to the answer to the documentation noting this difference in behavior and what options you have for having the action where you'd like (disable feed tracking or leave it on and use dynamic actions within the highlights panel).

Comment: Yes @KrisGoncalves, I did - and I've noticed that the case action display in the feed. Thank you for pointing that out.